# Stacks and Queue Amazon Interview Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Description**

You are given an array A of n integers. You have to make a queue and stack of the given integers. Queue should contain only prime numbers and stack should contain only composite numbers. All numbers in the array will be .
The rule to form the stack and queue is that you should be able to generate the array using the pop and dequeue operations.
Note : Please read this explanation carefully

Let the array A contains 5 integers : 7 , 21 , 18 , 3 , 12 then the content of queue and stack will be :
**Queue :** 7 , 3
**Stack :** 12 , 18 , 21
Now if you follow the rules of stack and queue then you see that you can generate the array using the pop operations of stack and dequeue operation of queue as follows :

```
dequeue from queue : 7
pop from stack : 7 , 21
pop from stack : 7 , 21 , 18
dequeue from queue : 7 , 21 , 18 , 3
pop from stack : 7 , 21 , 18 , 3 , 12
```

Thus for every array A you have to print the contents of queue in the first line and contents of stack in the second line.

**Input Format**
First line contains an integer n as input denoting total numbers of integers in the array.
Next line contains n space separated integers denoting the elements of array A.
Your output should print two arrays , one in each line. First line should be the contents of queue and second line should be the contents of stack.

**Output Format**
In the first line print the contents of queue and in second line print the contents of the stack.

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
5
7 21 18 3 12
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
7 3 
12 18 21
```

**My code**

```
backwas = input()
num1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
dic = {}

for num in num1:
    output = []
    for i in range(2,num+1):
        if num%i == 0:
            output.append(i)
        for item in set(output):
            output1 = list(set(output))
            dic[num] = output1
prime = []
comp = []

for num in num1:
    list1 = []
    list1 = list(dic[num])
    if len(list1) != 1:
        comp.append(str(num))
    else:
        prime.append(str(num))
   
print(" ".join(prime))
print(" ".join(comp))
```

**Problem with my code**

If you read properly you will immediately notice that the difficult part of this question is making two lists with a correct order, that is when some operations are done on them they give back the original list. My code fails to do so. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using Sieve of Eratosthenes and 2 arrays.

```py
num1 = [7,21,18,3,12]    # your list
n = max(num1)
prime = [True for i in range(n+1)] 
p = 2
while (p * p <= n):  #creating a Sieve using standard operations
    if (prime[p] == True): 
        for i in range(p * p, n+1, p): 
            prime[i] = False
    p += 1

prim, comp = [], []
for i in num1:
    if prime[i]:
        prim.append(i)
    else:
        comp.append(i)
for i in prim:
    print(i, end = " ")
print()
for i in comp[::-1]:
    print(i, end = " ")
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

The jist of the problem requires that given a sequence of space separated integers separate the list into primes stored in a Queue and Composite integers stored in a Stack. Output the primes in the que in FIFO order and the composite integers in the stack in LIFO order.

A *queue* is a linear First In First Out (FIFO) data structure.  A List data structure can be used as a queue if we use append() to implement enqueue() and pop() to implement dequeue(). However, lists are quite slow for this purpose because inserting or deleting an element at the beginning requires O(n) time. Using the dequeue class from the collections mnodule is the preferred queue implementation mechanism because append and pop operations take O(1) time.

A *stack* is a linear Last-In/First-Out (LIFO) or First-In/Last-Out (FILO) data structure.  In a similar manner to queue, a list data structure can be used to implement a stack, however  as with the queue situation if the list is long, performanvce issues will arise.  The dequeue class is therefore preferred for implementing a stack.

Based on the instructions, the first line of input gives the number of integers in the second line of input.
The second line consists of space separated integers.  The output is to consist of two lines.

- The first output line should present the prime numbers from the input in the order in which they were  entered.
- The second line should present the composite numbers from the input in the reverse order  in which they were entered.

Here is how I would have solved the problem:

```
#Utility to detect a Prime
def is_prime(n: int) -> bool:
    """
     Integer -> Boolean
     returns True if n is a prime number
    """
    if n == 2 or n == 3: return True
    if n < 2 or n%2 == 0: return False
    if n < 9: return True
    if n%3 == 0: return False
    r = int(sqrt(n))
    f = 5
    while f <= r:
        if n%f == 0:
            return False
        if n%(f+2) == 0:
            return False
        f +=6
    return True
```

Using a List approach

```
# Implementation with Lists assuming instr is list of integers
def list_method(instr: str):
    qlist = []
    stklist = []
    inLst = list(map(lambda x:int(x) ,instr.split()))
    for n in inLst:
        if is_prime(n):
            qlist.append(n)
        else:
            stklist.append(n)
    print(" ".join(map(lambda x: str(x), qlist)))
    print(" ".join(map(lambda x: str(x), stklist[::-1])))
```

Using dequeue Class

```
from collections import deque
def queue_method(instr: str):
    q = deque()
    stk = deque()
    inLst = list(map(lambda x:int(x) ,instr.split()))
    for n in inLst:
        if is_prime(n):
            q.append(n)
        else:
            stk.append(n)
    print(" ".join([str(q.popleft()) for i in range(len(q))]))
    print(" ".join([str(stk.pop()) for i in range(len(stk))]))
```